# Converting currency in MySQL using a join

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

A `currency` table (**based on USD**) which is updated constantly:

```
 +----+----------+-----------+
 | id | currency | value_usd |
 +----+----------+-----------+
 |  1 | USD      | 1         |
 |  2 | AUD      | 1.077315  |
 |  3 | GBP      | 0.620868  |
 |  4 | EUR      | 0.775338  |
 +----+----------+-----------+
```

And I have an `order` table where new orders are added:

```
+----+-------------+----------+
| id | sales_total | currency |
+----+-------------+----------+
|  1 | 100         | USD      |
|  2 | 50          | GBP      |
|  3 | 75          | EUR      |
|  4 | 60          | GBP      |
+----+-------------+----------+
```

I have an input of currency, which dictates the type of currency that I need to output the totals in, even though all orders are stored in various currencies.

For example, if `$currency = 'EUR';` all totals must be in EUR when querying the `order` table based on the rates in the `currency` table. Like so:

```
+----+-------------+----------+-----------------+
| id | sales_total | currency | converted_total |
+----+-------------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | 100         | USD      | 77.53           |
|  2 | 50          | GBP      | 62.44           |
|  3 | 75          | EUR      | 75.00           |
|  4 | 60          | GBP      | 74.92           |
+----+-------------+----------+-----------------+
```

How can I do this? I imagine that I'd need some sort of a `CASE` statement?

Comment: There's something wrong with this requirement. Currency conversions are only valid when actually performed by an exchange of currencies, e.g. at a bank. The rest of the time you are just feeding misinformation to the user. You should be dealing in either the currency of the pride of the item you're selling or the currency the user is going to use when paying. This is a business requirements issue, not a programming issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This oughta do it:

```
SELECT o.*, sales_total * (c2.value_usd / c1.value_usd) as converted_total,
       c2.currency as converted_currency
FROM `order` o
JOIN `currency` c1 ON o.currency = c1.currency
JOIN `currency` c2 ON c2.currency = 'EUR'
```

Hard to test without a sample DB though - the calculation might be off but the principle is clear.

Comment: Seems to work well! Just a few changes. The first join should be `o.currency = c1.currency` and the second should be `c2.currency = 'EUR'`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The factor for output currency you can get with a Sub-SELECT and the rest you do by joining the Tables on currency:

```
SELECT 
  t2.id AS id, 
  t2.sales_total AS sales_total, 
  t2.currency AS currency,
  (t2.sales_total / value_usd * (SELECT value_usd FROM t1 WHERE currency = 'EUR')) AS converted_total
FROM t2 JOIN t1
  ON t1.currency = t2.currency
```

Comment: I haven't tested this one, but assuming that it works, I believe it would be slower than Niels' above. I do appreciate it.

Comment: On one side my solution has a subselect, but this has to be evaluated only once, on the other side Niels' has one more JOIN. I just tested with some sample data (90k records). Mine was slightly faster: ~4.9 vs ~5.4 sec.

Comment: In that case, I stand corrected. The only other difference that I see is that if 'EUR' doesn't exist in `t1`, it will return the row with NULLs. While with Niels' code, rows will **not** be returned.

Comment: One other thing, if you have few records (less than ~160) in the `currency` table, will those benchmarks still look the same?

Comment: @JuanHoffmann kinda surprises me that a subquery is faster, I would expect neither to be. Did you use indexes on `currency.currency` and `order.currency`, and rerun the queries a few times to eliminate caching effects? With proper indexing even MySQL's crappy query optimizer should execute both extremely fast without significant measurable differences.

Comment: Actually my test was just very quick and dirty: The only indexes were the primary keys on the id columns. And the test was done on a remote server. So no real significance at all.

Comment: About the subquery: As far as I know, MySQL only evaluates it once for the whole query, thats why it is fast.