# Ordering price according to actual value by currency type in mysql

Tags: mysql, currency

I would be grateful if you help me. I just want to order products by price according to currency. There is two type of DB.

This is products table in first DB.

```
+----+--------------+-------+-------------+
| id | product_name | price | currency_id |
+----+--------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | X PRODUCT    | 11.00 |           1 |
|  2 | Y PRODUCT    | 10.00 |           2 |
+----+--------------+-------+-------------+
```

And this is currency table in first DB.

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | value |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | USD  |  1.00 |
|  2 | EUR  |  1.26 |
+----+------+-------+
```

This is second option for DB structure. There is only one table.

```
+----+--------------+-------+----------+
| id | product_name | price | currency |
+----+--------------+-------+----------+
|  1 | X PRODUCT    | 11.00 | USD      |
|  2 | Y PRODUCT    | 10.00 | EUR      |
+----+--------------+-------+----------+
```

I don't know which DB I should use and I don't know how to order by price according to actual price in USD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the first option (synthetic keys in case a currency changes name), you'd end up with a simple JOIN to get the correct ordering;

```
SELECT p.*, value*price adjusted_price
FROM products p
JOIN currency c
  ON c.id = p.currency_id
ORDER BY adjusted_price
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cb4d/1).

The "adjusted price" column is the price adjusted to USD, and then you can just order by that.

Comment: That's what I want. works like a charm. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about index and performance? The order by `adjusted_price` is not indexed.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that it's better to keep your prices within one currency. And if you need to keep another currency — just create another field for that `usd_price` or the whole new table with currency prices: 
`product_prices: product_id(int), currency_id(int), price(double)`

UPD: create method for actual prices for different currencies

```
def usd_price
  price * currency_rates[:usd]
end
```

Comment: you mean that should I create fields for each currency in products table ? Then how can I make them updated by exchange rate in mysql? I want to keep updated exchange rates and I want to order products by actual price. I don't know how to query ordering by actual price.

Comment: I am dumbass. Please give me complete query and working example :) I found a thread about it but I really didn't understand it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734194/converting-currency-in-mysql-using-a-join?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @OğuzCanSertel actually, if you want to all your prices in database you will need to find a way to update it once your currency_rate changes.

Comment: I will update currency table. But How can I order products according to the real price in USD.if you look at products; X product is 11 dolar and Y product is 10 Euro. When I order ASC by price the first item must be X product. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @OğuzCanSertel keep all your products in one currency and then show to users the other currency if needed with method (and persist it if you need to)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem already solved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169908/ordering-price-according-to-actual-value-by-currency-type-in-mysql/26170249#26170249